# Kali linux Proxychains

Tags: proxy, kali-linux, encoding

When im trying to do this code "proxychains firefox duckduckgo.com" this pops up:

```
proxychains firefox www.duckduckgo.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified"
```

Why does it pop up?

This is my Proxy code

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 3.1
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

 Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#               http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#               socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#               http    192.168.39.93   8080
#
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
socks5  127.0.0.1 1080
```

Comment: Does `firefox www.duckduckgo.com` print the same error?

Comment: Yes it does i did everything i even changed it to firefox google.com but the same thing happens-Kamil Maciorowski

Comment: So this has nothing to do with `proxychains`. It's about `DISPLAY` variable not being specified. Did you run these commands in a graphical environment?

Comment: Yea about so it displays the variable not being specified but i don't really know what graphical environment means sense i just started a month ago.